# XMPP broker support in activemq 5.7 and 5.8

Tags: xmpp, activemq-classic

IS XMPP broker supported in activemq version 5.7 and 5.8.  I am able to create topic but during creation of queue it is throwing me exceptions.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMPP module is there is both v5.7 and v5.8.  As of v5.8 its deprecated and won't be included going forward.   The module is not well maintained and is quite tricky to get working correctly which is why we have chosen to drop it.

Since you haven't indicated what the exception is there no way to guess what might be going wrong.  I'd suggest looking into one of the many other protocols that are well supported in AMQ like STOMP for instance.

Edit:  From the exception you've given in the comments it looks as though the activemq-xmpp.jar is not located on the classpath.  Make sure you put that jar into the proper location so your broker can find the fictory bean for the XMPP Transport.

Comment: Hi Tim, Here is the exception I get Caught: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [xmpp]
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [xmpp]